# set a variable in mutliple places in a master page

Tags: variables, dynamic

I am trying to grab a string of text from the .vb file of my master page. I need to render this text out as part of the class definitions.

E.g.  <div id="######ContentArea">

I need to replace the ###### with a string I have created in the .vb file.

How do you do this? Or is there an easier way  = NEWBIE here!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make this change on enough pages, you should consider removing that div from the master page.  Otherwise it would be helpful to know exactly what you are trying to do and why you are trying to do it that way.

Comment: I have a site which has 11 different sections and the existing css is setup so that each section title is part of the css.

I am trying to capture the section based on the folder structure, so that I can assign the css classes dynamically through the master page.

If its in the Housing folder - set the css to HousingContainer, HousingNav, etc.

The section title has to go into a few places.

Comment: If it is based on folder structure, you should be able to get away with using nested master pages.  In the root folder, use a single master page that has everything except the part that needs to change, then in each sub folder, create a nested master page which adds the values that would change for each section.  Then just be sure to change all of the pages to look at the master pages for their section instead of the master page.  Be sure to test it in steps and don't do the whole thing at once.